# Batch: IF NOT EXIST statement with a variable having the name of a file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

The part with IF NOT EXIST give this error

> The syntax of the command is incorrect

The statement is supposed to verify that %premier% (could be a .bat file) doesn't exist in the current directory.

```
:para2
echo Donnez 2 parametres
set /p premier=Le premier fichier a echanger: 
set /p deuxieme=Le deuxieme fichier a echanger:     
IF NOT EXIST %premier% (
    echo Les valeurs entrees sont erronees; les fichiers devraient exister
    echo %premier% n'existe pas
    GOTO para2
)
IF NOT EXIST %deuxieme% (
    echo Les valeurs entrees sont erronees; les fichiers devraient exister
    echo %deuxieme% n'existe pas
    GOTO para2
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have spaces in a file name. You need to quote the variables in these 2 lines:

```
IF NOT EXIST "%premier%" (
```

and

```
IF NOT EXIST "%deuxieme%" (
```

Comment: Thanks my firiend: the problem was solved with the quotes :)